# Type '() => boolean' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2322)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I kindly I need help rectifying this typeScript error:

```
Type '() => boolean' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2322)
```

Below is a sample of my code:

```
export const Palindrome:React.FC<{}> = () => {

    const results = ():boolean => {

        const int = 121;
        return String(int) === String(int).split('').reverse().join();
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {results}
        </div>
    )

}
```

Comment: It doesn't know how to render your `function` as a JSX element. What are you trying to render inside that `div`?

Comment: Please do not edit your question to remove the original problem. I have rolled back your edit. Instead, accept one of the answers that pointed out the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to **call** the function, you are passing its reference instead, which React doesn't know what to do with.

```
export const Palindrome:React.FC<{}> = () => {
    const results = ():boolean => {
        const int = 121;
        return String(int) === String(int).split('').reverse().join();
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {results()} {/* add () like here */}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling the results function. Change to this

```
return (
    <div>
        {results()}
    </div>
)
```

Comment: I just rectified it. thanks for your comment.